# Flag declined on a question

Tags: discussion

I just wanted to ask if for that question, flagging it as 'unclear' was ok ? ([How can I configure each Windows user to have unique ip address](https://serverfault.com/questions/722303/how-can-i-configure-each-windows-user-to-have-unique-ip-address))

My flag got declined, and later @womble asked the user to clarify itself. Thus kinda mean for me that it's indeed unclear :)

Edit : To answer Iain on the reason I used, and why I asked there.

[image]

Comment: That flag that you show isn't an unclear flag it's a flag asking why a flag was declined. You don't mention this at all in your question which now appears unclear itself.

Comment: @Iain Check the timestamp ... and read my first line please. "I just wanted to ask if for that question, flagging it as 'unclear' was ok ?" I did flag "unclear". The other flag was just because I seen a moderator asking the user, so my error, should had use meta directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Clarification: I was the mod that declined the initial "unclear" flag; I didn't decline the "meta" flag)

When you flag a question for mod attention, you are requesting closure.  As Michael Hampton described, it turned up in the close review queue and, as I believed the question wasn't worthy of closure, I clicked "Leave Open".  A mod clicking "Leave Open" is not some sort of super-vote that causes the question to be forever left open.  All it does is clear the flag (if I had skipped the review, another mod would still have had to deal with it).

I'll note that the question hasn't received a single community close vote as of now, so if you're waiting for the 5 community votes to close it, you might be waiting a while.

I did not feel this question warranted closure, because although it *is* unclear as written, it has the potential to be useful, and the question-asker has at least a little bit of engagement with SF, so there's a reasonable basis to believe that the question-asker will return and edit their question to clarify.  So far, no luck, but not everyone obsesses about their SF account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didnt know you did the review. I didnt mean to do a witchhunt there, so I appreciate your time. I maybe badly use the flag option. For me I use it only for community moderation, except case like spam or abuse. A example from another review I did is http://serverfault.com/questions/718937/centos-rootnologin. I flagged it the 5 sept, and was closed today. I just feel that it can somehow help to flag. My misinterpretation is maybe that Iam under 3k, the flag does maybe not mean the same

Comment: I don't feel witch-hunted, no harm done.  The general "theme" of flagging is that it should be limited to cases where community moderators *can't* deal with something (converting non-answers to comments, deleting abusive/spammy comments) or where action *has* to be taken quickly or with "extra" authority (stopping on-going abuse, banning users, etc).

Comment: I agree, gonna wait for my 3k to continue :) but SO team did it confusing as I did like 100 close vote and it show helpful in my profile, even if im lower of 3k, but you are right that all close question only show the 5 member that the vote counted (over 3k)

Answer (score 2):

This flag was declined automatically by the system.

When you flagged the post as "off-topic", it was placed in the [close review queue](https://serverfault.com/review/close). Then, [it was reviewed](https://serverfault.com/review/close/220933) and when it was reviewed as "Leave Open" your flag was dismissed.

Comment: Will mark as answer, but I still don't know why the moderator didn't waited the 5 community vote, as even another moderator found it unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason provided but I can well imagine that the moderator declined the flag to educate you in their usage. What did you expect a moderator to do that you could not do yourself ?

Moderators are there to handle things that the community cannot handle itself. You have more than 50 rep so in this particular case you could have left a comment asking the OP to clarify their question (that is after all one of the functions of comments).

Comment: Yes, but I flagged it and told the OP it was unclear. The moderator can just bypass the review if he don't agree and wait for the 5 community votes. It was not in a hurry to close too, but I seen better wrote question flagged unclear.

Comment: After womble answer, I now understand your point. Was a newbie error from me. As I cant see the 'close' option. I thought that flagging a close vote was like casting a close vote. It's just confusing, as the mouse-over text for the flag is "flag this posts for serious problem or moderator attention", and when you click "flag" , the last option is "in need of moderator intervention". Will read the FAQ next time, as each option need a moderator intervention, even if I click simply that the question is offtopic.